# Why MySQL LIMIT condition search with subquery is faster than simple search?

Tags: mysql, subquery, limit

Mentioned in *Alibaba Java Code Convention*, see https://yq.aliyun.com/articles/69327 Rule 3.2.7

```
SELECT a.* FROM table1 a, (SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE condition LIMIT 100000, 20) b WHERE a.id = b.id
```

is much faster than

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE condition LIMIT 100000, 20
```

This article explains that MySQL will fetch 100020 result rows and eliminate first 100000 instead of only fetch 20 rows.

Is it true in MySQL query engine? May be a bug or defect?

**UPDATE**

assume table1 contains MANY columns (10+) and condition is not too complicated (e.g. `ip LIKE '192.168.%'`)

Comment: It is not always true. It depends if the fields that appear in `condition` are indexed or not (and how are they indexed and how are they used in `condition`).

Comment: and depends on how much columns selected, tested just now :-)

Comment: Actually, if `condition` contains columns that are not in any index, MySQL is forced to read 100020 rows from the table data in both cases. In theory this situation makes the first query worse (because it has to read the table data twice) but in practice, most probably, the caching (internal MySQL caching and file system caching) prevents it to turn into a disaster.

Comment: In which order have you tested the queries? Did you execute the 2nd one first?

Comment: @auntyellow N.B has a point in the question above. MySQL keeps an internal cache and if you run the two queries in sequence there is a high probability that the second query uses data that is already in cache (it runs faster but the query itself doesn't have any contribution to the speed).

Comment: `SELECT * FROM user_login_log WHERE ip LIKE '%10%' LIMIT 150000, 20` **always** 0.29xx Sec, `SELECT * FROM user_login_log a, (SELECT pkey FROM user_login_log WHERE ip LIKE '%10%' LIMIT 150000, 20) b WHERE a.pkey = b.pkey` **always** 0.16xx Sec, in one of my servers. First SQL will be faster if I select fewer columns.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's true.

The 1st query only scan 100020 result rows for field id then scan 20 rows full fields, but the second query scan 100020 for all fields.

Comment: *"but the second query scan 100020 for all fields"* -- this is not entirely true. It depends on the fields that appear in `condition` and the indexes of the table.

Comment: @axiac: in my statement I assume that the where condition is true for the first 100020 rows.